# Using StatelessWidget with method variable or Stateful widget?

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter and I am looking what might be the pro's / con's of some specific way of solving this. I have a simple widget which is used as a ModalBottomSheet. It will contain a form with multiple text fields to submit some data - which is returned in the callback. Example:

```
class SimpleBottomPopupSheet extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onSubmit;

  const BottomPopupSheet({this.onSubmit});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String text;
    return Column(children: [
      TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        onChanged: (value) {
          text = value;
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Do something with the text
          onSubmit(text);
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: Text("SUBMIT"),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

This seems to work, but I am wondering if this is a correct way to use it (there will be more than just one text field). It feels like it should be a stateful widget as it is keeping the state of the input.
Any best practices around this use case?

Comment: This will not work if `build` is spontaneously called by flutter. Your `text` variable will reset and become null. As you noticed, this is storing state, so you should be using a stateful widget here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other comments are correct. This should be a StatefulWidget as any rebuilds of the widget will cause the "text" parameter to be reset. A rather naive and basic example of how to convert your StatelessWidget into a StatefulWidget is below:

```dart
class SimpleBottomPopupSheet extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onSubmit;

  const SimpleBottomPopupSheet({this.onSubmit});

  @override
  State<SimpleBottomPopupSheet> createState() => _SimpleBottomPopupSheetState();
}

class _SimpleBottomPopupSheetState extends State<SimpleBottomPopupSheet> {

  String _text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(children: [
      TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        onChanged: (value) {
          _text = value;
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Do something with the text
          widget.onSubmit(_text);
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
        child: const Text("SUBMIT"),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your widget should be a StatefulWidget. What you wrote won't work because each time the user types something the text variable will be wiped out (and other nasty things :))

You should have a look at Flutter Form tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation!

You should use StatelessWidget only when the widget does not update its values! Otherwise, you should use a StatefulWidget or more complex state management solution. Again you can find many guides on flutter.dev!

(But using a method onSubmit to return the data to the previous view/widget is a good idea)